# swift 4 wrong json array parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoder

I have the json like this:

```
{"result":0,"data":[{\"ID":7,"TITLE":"123"},{\"ID":8,"TITLE":"123"}]}
```

I have the struct like this:

```
struct ResponseResult: Decodable {
let result: Int
let data: [IdResponseResult]
}

struct IdResponseResult: Decodable {
let ID: Int
let TITLE: String
}
```

So, when I run request like this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://xxx.xxx.xxx",headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try? decoder.decode(ResponseResult.self, from: json)
                print(response.value)
                completion(result)
            }
        }
```

and print response.value I'm getting this:

```
   data =     (
               {
            "ID" = 7;
            TITLE = 123;
        },
                {
            "ID" = 8;
            TITLE = 123;
        }
    );
    result = 0;
}
```

And I cant parse it. How can i resolve it??

Comment: Change your structs to be named correctly; `Response` and `Resp2`

Comment: edited structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the decoding failure is caused by the struct `resp2`

```
struct resp2: Decodable {
  let ID: Int
  let TITLE: String
 }
```

you are defining `TITLE:String`, but in the JSON you have an `Int` `"TITLE":123`.
In case you really want a `String` (make sense, since is a "Title"), you may need to fix the server side.

---

**edit**:

I tried the Decodable as it is now and I am able to recover your structures, you may check with:

```
let string = "{\"result\": 0,\"data\": [{\"ID\": 7,\"TITLE\": \"123\"}, {\"ID\": 8,\"TITLE\": \"123\"}]}"
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let result = try? decoder.decode(ResponseResult.self, from: data!)
    print(result?.data.first?.TITLE ?? "") // 123
} catch _ {
}
```

Then I guess there has to be something weird when you receive the data from the service.

Comment: But in the json it is actiually String: 

{"result":0,"data":[{\"ID":7,"TITLE":"123"},{\"ID":8,"TITLE":"123"}]

Why it represents in such way like in the topic?

Comment: Above was written: `"TITLE":123` Anyway, I guess you still have the problem right?

Comment: yes, I've edited the topic, but I still have the problem. I've changed TITLE to INT - no result, changed to String - still no luck

Comment: try to make all the types optional like: `Int?`, `String?` and so on, moreover look at `{"result":0,"data":[{\"ID":7,"TITLE":"123"},{\"ID":8,"TITLE":"123"}]` it missing the final `}`

Comment: I've made all types optional, but still no luck

Comment: parse your data with: `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any]`, move away from the Decodable (for the moment), investigate better if the JSON data is valid

Comment: I've tried like you have written, so, i have the dictionary in a variable json. But how can I retrieve items from array data?

Comment: just a moment, I am testing your Decodable, which is working